# Jenkins Workflow Plugin Visualisation

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I'm investigating the Jenkins Workflow plugin, so far I think its brilliant.

Is their a way to visualize the pipeline that is defined by the workflow script, I've come across something that CloudBees say they have but I'm presuming that isn't freely available, does anyone know of any others?

Answer (score 3):

Jenkins Workflow visualization is now open sourced by Cloudbees as promised - https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-stage-view-plugin

Answer (score 2):

I just stumbled over this statement in a blog post from the Jenkins/Hudson founder, at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-dev/vbXK7JJekFw:

> To reinforce the message that workflow is the future, CloudBees is going to open-source our workflow stage view plugin that was previously a part of CloudBees Jenkins Enterprise.

So it sounds like it's not freely available, but may be in the near future.

Comment: Well that's good news, well done CloudBees for being part of the community.